# Java not outputting to terminal as expected (new lines appearing)

Tags: java, bluej

The code I have is below. I am expecting it to spit out something like:

> SN=12345678 EX=  73 CW=  73 Mark =  73.0
>
> SN=87654321 EX=  50 CW=  70 Mark =  60.0

But I am getting:

> .
>
> .
>
> .
>
> SN=12345678 EX=  73 CW=  73 Mark =  73.0
>
> .
>
> .
>
> SN=87654321 EX=  50 CW=  70 Mark =  60.0

(With a load of extra linebreaks (demonstrated by periods))

I really can't work out where these are coming from.

Please point me in the right direction!

```
class Main
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    { 
        int sN = 1;
        int cwMark;
        int exMark;
        double Mark;
        while ( sN != 0 )
        {
            sN = CIO.getInt();
            cwMark = CIO.getInt();
            exMark = CIO.getInt();
            Mark = ((double)(exMark + cwMark)/2);
            System.out.print("SN=");
            System.out.print( (int) sN );
            System.out.print(" EX=  ");
            System.out.print( (int) exMark );
            System.out.print(" CW=  ");
            System.out.print( (int) cwMark );
            System.out.print(" Mark =  ");
            System.out.print(Mark);
        }
    }
}
```

getInt is defined as:

```
public static int getInt()
  {
    String res = getLine();                          
    int value = 0;                                 
    try
    {
      value = Integer.parseInt( res.trim() );
    }
    catch ( NumberFormatException ex ) 
    {                                                 
    }
    return value;                                   
  }
```

Comment: You don't even have a line break in the code you show. Some important code is missing.

Comment: What is `CIO`? how is it defined?

Comment: The problem might be in the getInt method or (less probable) in another thread.

Comment: well thanks, I don't want it done, i just was wondering if anybody could spot from my code why those linebreaks were showing. That is all the code i have. CIO is an imported class to allow imput from the console.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what `CIO` is. Where are you exactly getting the input from? I could theorize that you're obtaining your integers from the console, which would explain what you're seeing: you're getting input from the console, and printing to the same console. To input an integer, someone has to hit a newline somewhere, and that newline is being echoed to the console.

I might be smoking something but I think this has to do with the definition of `CIO`.

**EDIT**: as you confirmed that CIO interacts with the console, this is now clear. When you invoke `getInt`, you end up parsing the input *except* for the newline character. As the console is defined to echo back every keystroke that it gets, the newline character (which serves as both an input delimiter *and* a newline/linefeed character) has to be output somewhere... which is exactly why you see newline characters in your output.

For example, if you add another `getInt` somewhere there, you'll see 4 newline characters in the output, instead of 3.

Comment: This looks like college code to me. He thinks the problem is in the part where he's printing, but since he's in college he doesn't know; he "knows" where the error might be coming from and wants us to spot it.

You cannot explain the phenomenon of extra newlines because he's not running the same piece of code he's posted.

Comment: Whether or not this is college code is immaterial. We can't expect people to always be able to provide full contextual information: sometimes they don't have access to it, and sometimes (as you suggest) they're not even aware of it. So the best we can do is hypothesize & ask for additional information. Even if this is "college code" as you suggest, this is the only way in which we can help the guy learn.

Comment: Yes, it is college code. Week 1 Java. I don't want an answer, I was hoping someone could point me in the direction I should look for the issue.
The CIO class is one my University produces for us to use for inputs etc. I have edited in the definition of getInt into my OP.

Comment: So `CIO` does interact with the console... I'll edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

The code you have posted won't produce any new lines at all (not even between separate sets of values). How are you running the code? Are you sure the code you have posted is the same version that is being executed?

Also, a couple of points:

- You don't need to cast `sN`, `exMark` and `cwMark` to ints, they are already declared as such.
- You should change the name of the `Mark` variable to `mark` - names starting with upper-case letters are usually only used for classes and interfaces.

Comment: Please use the "Add Comment" button.

Comment: Agreed, not a real answer but still, no need to downvote as much as it's obvious the output doesn't come from the posted code.

Comment: Yes, this is definitely the output of the code I have posted. If I change the last line to println, I get a third linebreak.

Comment: It was stin - this was creating a new line. The College marking systems ignore "#" when checking, so I printed one of those onto the getInt request line. I've passed this coursework piece now!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what CIO is (some stdin?), but it's resposible:

```
sN = CIO.getInt();
cwMark = CIO.getInt();
exMark = CIO.getInt();
```